# How to add background color to UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

I have added `BarButtonItem` using system image `"plus.color.fill"`, then I got small image with background blue colored.

How to add background color or how to increase the size of `BarButton`.

I have to get the button like in image below. Currently getting a small image

[image: view BarButton image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the background color of a UIBarButtonItem on iOS 7+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348952/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-uibarbuttonitem-on-ios-7)

Comment: Custom UIButton on UINavigationBar could solve your problem. If you're talking about the size of the button on UINavigationBar, you could also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079135/ios-set-size-of-button-in-title-of-uinavigationbar

Comment: Nothing got worked @Turtleeeeee  I think those are in objective c.

Comment: @Turtleeeeee Im not trying to add image  me trying to add color as background of barbutton

Comment: That's the same. OC code can be translated into swift. As I could remember, UIBarButtonItem can't easily change size. Customizing a button and put it on will be a better choice. But if color is the only thing you want to change, try to set `tintColor` on `UIBarButtonItem`

Comment: @Turtleeeeee not working

Comment: Show me your code. Changing color of UIBarButtonItem is really not hard.